# Get draggable parent container

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have 2 containers.

Both of them is a draggable and dropable, to be sure I can move tags from one to another.

In the drop function I check the id of containers. Based on the name of the id, I decide, should I add a tag to a user or should I remove it from the user.

Let's says, there is a container div for `existsTagsContiner`. This contains the tags of the user.

The other container is `userTagsContainer` what contains all of the tags what are not belongs to user.

Both of these container has a class: `.draggableTagContainer`

Everything is works fine, when I move the tag from one to other, ajax made the operations, and a message appears for user.

For example, if user moves a tag from `existsTagsContiner` to `userTagsContainer` then I should add the tag to user.

But, and here comes my problem: if I am moving a tag from `existsTagsContiner` to `existsTagsContiner` (so no movement happened, just a drag and drop in the same container), the message appears too!

Definitely it should not happen. So, what I want to achive is to get the "source" id of the container. If the "source" is the same as `$(this).attr('id')` in the drop function, I just do nothing.

I've added a comment, where I need to get the original container name.

Here is my code.

```
    $('#existsTagsContiner, #userTagsContainer').droppable({
        tolerance: "intersect",
        accept: ".draggableTagContainer",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var tagId = $(ui.helper.context).data('id');
            $('#tagId').val(tagId);

            //At here I need something like $(ui.helper.___SOURCE___)

            if ($(this).attr('id') === 'existsTagsContiner') {
                $.removeTagFromUser();
            } else {
                $.saveTagToUser();
            }
            $('#tagId').val('0');
            if (!$(this).find('ul').length) {
                $(this).html('<ul>');
            }
            $(this).find('ul').append($(ui.draggable));
        }
    });


    $('.draggableTagContainer').draggable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).addClass("draggableTagContainer");
        },
        appendTo: 'parent',
        cursor: "move",
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid',
        cancel: ".draggableTagDelete",
    });
```

**UPDATE**

That could be a workaround, if I add a `data-from` to the `li` when start to drag. **But maybe there is a built in function for this, this is what I want to know.**

This is the workaround. In the `start` function of draggable add:

```
 $(ui.helper).data('from', $(this).closest('.tagContainer').attr('id'));
```

in the droppable `drop` function add:

```
if ($(this).attr('id') === ui.helper.data('from')) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: remove that start function and try..

Comment: that start function just add a class for cloned element, nothing wrong with it.